# How to make prediction using the Boston housing dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working through a tutorial for predicting housing prices. The code works, but I'm trying to make a prediction on a new, unknown array, but I keep getting and error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The code works, but I want to test on a new example:

```
X_new = [['15.7','20.5','18.9', '21.7', '20.4', '18.2', '19.9', '23.1', '17.5', '20.2', '18.2', 
'13.6', '19.6']]

reg.predict(X_new)
```

I get the following error message: "UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'matmul' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype(' dtype('

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Do I have to change the X_new to a list of strings, or keep them as a numpy array?

Comment: Worth comparing your `x_test` with your `x_new` in terms of datatypes and shapes. Can you provide a row of `x_test` in your question for comparison?

Comment: x_test.shape
(167, 13)

X_new
[['15.7',
  '20.5',
  '18.9',
  '21.7',
  '20.4',
  '18.2',
  '19.9',
  '23.1',
  '17.5',
  '20.2',
  '18.2',
  '13.6',
  '19.6']]

Comment: Please provide the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) per the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I think I needed to change the array to float to get a result:
    my_array = np.array(X_new, dtype=float)
    reg.predict(my_array)]

my result is as follows: array([[29.99003492]])

For the Boston housing dataset, I times 30 by 10000 to get the predicted housing price? so 300,000 is the predicted house price?