# How to Predict a new housing price using SciKit-Learn?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I currently have no experience with Machine Learning so I decided to try an online course. The project I am attempting is the Boston Housing dataset.

I wanted to know how to add a new DataFrame, boston_df2, to my current DataFrame, boston_df1 so that I can make a new prediction. I tried using the append option below. My ultimate goal is to make a price prediction on boston_df_append (boston_df1 + boston_df2).

I noticed that someone asked a very similar question but there wasn't a clear answer to me: [How to make prediction using the Boston housing dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640597/how-to-make-prediction-using-the-boston-housing-dataset).

Please don't mark me down for asking a similar question. I am still learning. =)

```
#import boston housing dataset

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

#load boston data

boston = load_boston()

boston;

#create boston_df1 DataFrame

boston_df1 = pd.DataFrame(boston['data'], columns = boston['feature_names'])

boston_df1['target'] = pd.Series(boston['target'])

#Random seed

np.random.seed(42)

#create the data

X = boston_df1.drop('target', axis=1)

y = boston_df1['target']

#split into train and test

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

#instantiate and fit model

model = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)

#make predictions on new data   

y_preds = model.predict(X_test)

y_preds[-1]

#check model score (accuracy)

model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

I would like to add data for a new house, boston_df2, to make a prediction on the price of the house.

```
#add boston_df2 DataFrame

boston_df2 = {'CRIM': 0.6, 'ZN': 0.0, 'INDUS': 2.5, 'CHAS': 0.0, 'NOX': 0.6, 'RM': 8.0, 'AGE': 80, 'DIS': 5.0, 'RAD': 2.0, 'TAX': 300.0, 'PTRATIO': 20.0, 'B': 400.0, 'LSTAT': 10.0}

boston_df_append = boston_df1.append(boston_df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can implement this? Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer! =)

Comment: you should use model.predict simiilarily to what you do with X_test

Comment: Thank you @Gábor Pálovics! I am not sure how to do this but will try to figure it out. Any way you can show me with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To predict a new price started from your dict:

```
boston_df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(boston_df2, orient='index').T
boston_df2['target'] = model.predict(boston_df2)
```

```
>>> boston_df2['target']
0    35.981
Name: target, dtype: float64

>>> boston_df2
   CRIM   ZN  INDUS  CHAS  NOX   RM   AGE  DIS  RAD    TAX  PTRATIO      B  LSTAT  target
0   0.6  0.0    2.5   0.0  0.6  8.0  80.0  5.0  2.0  300.0     20.0  400.0   10.0  35.981
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Corralien for your time! I am very grateful for your help. =)